# Restart Windows Computer with x minutes pause

Tags: bios, shutdown, uefi, reboot

I have a computer that I've turned into a personal server, I want it to shut down every day at 3 am for 10 minutes to reduce the hardware temperature, and restart it after that.

Is there any way to do this ? Or something close to this ( hibernation etc... ) ?

I think that if it's possible, it should be at bios/uefi level ( in the case of a complete shut down ).

( OS: Windows )

Thanks

Comment: Does your BIOS provide options to set a wake-up time that can turn the machine back on at a certain time of day?

Comment: I'll check, If it's so it should be easy to create a windows planified task to shut it down at wake-up time - 10 minutes. Thanks